# How do I fix the text in the longtable that goes beyond the margins of the page?

Tags: tables, longtable, page-breaking

I have a problem with a longtable where the text exceeds the page margin. Like the following image:
[image: problem]

I want the text to be redirected to the next page like the following image:
[image: wish]

I've tried `\raggedbottom`, but it doesn't work.

Here's my current work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\section{The Section}
\lipsum{6}
\begin{longtable}{|p{1.21cm}|p{2.49cm}|p{2.74cm}|p{1.59cm}|p{3.75cm}|p{3cm}|}
 \caption{table caption}\label{tabel1}\\
 \hline
  No&Name&Know&Text&Answer 1&Answer 2 \\
  \hline
  1&Alone Johnson&This is the text&You know it& \lipsum[1-2].&Yes I know \\
  \hline
  2&John Date&Something to write&I dont know    &\lipsum[4]&Yes you know \\
  \hline
  \end{longtable}



\end{document}
```

Comment: longtable only allows page breaks between rows, it never breaks entries in a single cell: a `p` column entry is a `\parbox` and like a normal `\parbox` does not allow page breaking.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. So, what do you think I should use to fulfill my wish?

Comment: split by hand put the first part of the text in the existing celll then have an extra row `&&& end of text &&\\ `  to take the text that has to cary over to the next page

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. But it doesn't work well enough.

Comment: sorry but that is the only possibility with longtable, in what way does it not work well, you should be able to get exactly the output that you would get from an automatic page break. (set `\parfillskip=0pt` before the broken paragraph so the last line on the first page is full length not short

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What about options other than longtable? is there any and do you know anything that can fulfill my wish?

Comment: no' it is really quite hard, you show an easy case but if a table package wanted to offer this it would have to find compatible break points in every cell in the row, which might have different baselines or images or anything. None of the well known table packages will do this.

Comment: note here I am talking just of page breaking and running off the bottom. your example uses fixed with `p` columns forcing the table to be wider than the page which is an unrelated issue, easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the paragraphs by hand you can insert `\parfillskip=0pt` so the initial text before the page break has a full length last line and does not look like end of paragraph.

First however, you need to adjust the widths of the columns so they fit the text width.
Your total `p` column width was already wider than the page  so no table with that specification could fit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\section{The Section}
\lipsum{6}


\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\small
\begin{longtable}{@{}|l|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.59cm}|p{3.75cm}|p{1.5cm}|@{}}
 \caption{table caption}\label{tabel1}\\
 \hline
  No&Name&Know&Text&Answer 1&Answer 2 \\
  \hline
  1&Alone Johnson&This is the text&You know it& 

% \NewLipsumPar{% {1}
\parfillskip=0pt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant
morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Mauris ut leo.
Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus
vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor
gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
 quis, viverra
ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Ae-
&Yes I know \\

&&&& 
nean faucibus.
Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh
mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci
sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

\parfillskip=0pt
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan
bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi
ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante.
Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla
ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.&\\

  \hline
  2&John Date&Something to write&I dont know    &

%\NewLipsumPar{% {4}
\parfillskip=0pt
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae
lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea
Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae
lacus tincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus
convallis augue.
&Yes you know\\
&&&&
 Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum
 fermentum wisi. Aenean
 dictumst. Integer tempus
convallis augue. Etiam facilisis. Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean
placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed gravida sollicitudin, felis odio
placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim. Nunc vitae tortor.
Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae risus porta
vehicula.

& \\
  \hline
  \end{longtable}



\end{document}
```